# I'm trying to reverse the changes on the button when I press it the second time, but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

I'm trying to reverse the changes on the button when I press it the second time, but it doesn't work. The first click does work as desired. However, when i click the same button the second time it doesn't do anything.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("signInBtn");
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let a = 1;
  const title = document.getElementById("title1");
  const removeName = document.getElementById("remove_name");
  const name1 = document.getElementById("name1");
  const first = document.getElementById("first");
  const removeCheckbox = document.getElementById("remove_checkbox");
  const question = document.getElementById("question");
  const signUpBtn = document.getElementById("signup");
  const btn = document.querySelector("#signInBtn")
  if (a === 1) {
    title.innerHTML = "Log In";
    removeName.style.display = "none";
    name1.style.display = "none";
    first.style.display = "none";
    removeCheckbox.style.display = "none";
    question.firstChild.textContent = "Don't have an account?";
    btn.innerHTML = "Sign Up";
    signUpBtn.innerHTML = "Log In";
    question.style.marginTop = "35px";
    signUpBtn.style.marginTop = "45px";
    return a = 0;

  } else if (a === 0) {
    // Apply the effects
    title.innerHTML = "Get Started Now";
    removeName.style.display = "block";
    name1.style.display = "block";
    first.style.display = "block";
    removeCheckbox.style.display = "block";
    question.firstChild.textContent = "Have an account?";
    btn.innerHTML = "Sign in";
    signUpBtn.innerHTML = "Sign Up";
    question.style.marginTop = "23px";
    signUpBtn.style.marginTop = "35px";
    return a = 1;

  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Start Page</title>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/96bfde6bea.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.0/css/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="working.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="image">
    <div class="navigation">
      <div><i id="icon" class="fa-solid fa-bolt fa-spin"></i>RoRo, Inc.</div>
      <div><i id="home" class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>Home</div>
      <div><i id="info" class="fa-solid fa-circle-info"></i>About Us</div>
      <div><i id="ai" class="fa-brands fa-codepen"></i>Products</div>
    </div>
    <div id="frame">
      <h1 id="title1">Get Started Now</h1>
      <div id="bar"></div>
      <form>
        <div class="name" id="remove_name">
          <div id="name1">Name</div>
          <i id="first" class="fa-solid fa-user fa-lg"></i>
          <input type="text" id="contact" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div class="email">
          <div id="email1">Email Address</div>
          <i id="second" class="fa-solid fa-envelope fa-lg"></i>
          <input type="email" id="address123" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="password">
          <div id="password1">Password</div>
          <i id="third" class="fa-solid fa-lock fa-lg"></i>
          <input type="password" id="lockage" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox" id="remove_checkbox">
          <div><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">I agree to the <a href="#">terms & conditions</a></div>
        </div>
      </form>

      <button type="button" id="signup">Sign Up</button>

      <div class="or">
        <div id="left-bar"></div>
        <div id="or">Or</div>
        <div id="right-bar"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="options" id="remove_options">
        <button type="button" id="google" class="transformup"><i class="fab fa-google fa-2x"></i></i><p>Sign in with Google</p></button>
        <button type="button" id="apple"><i class="fa fa-apple"></i><p>Sign in with Apple</p></i></button>
      </div>
      <div id="question"><span>Have an account?</span><button type="button" id="signInBtn">  Sign in</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="working.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried to use alternatives to event listener such as a function and call it on click. It still doesn't work.

Comment: You need to move the declaration and initialization of the `a` variable outside the function. You're setting it to `1` every time you click the button.

Comment: You could also just check the value of `title.innerHTML` and use that instead of the variable.